# Synonyms of an object property in Protégé

Tags: ontology, protege

How can i add some synonyms to an object property in Protégé? (i'm using Protégé 5.2).

Comment: Do you mean equivalent properties? Create two object properties, press "Equivalent To" in the [Description view](http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/views/object-property-description/) of the first property, choose the second property.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I don't want to create new properties. Exemple: Organizer presents the Speaker. I want to mention that we can express the relation "present" using the verbe Announce. Is it possible?